# AVG function works but not COUNT but can't figure out why

Tags: mysql

For some reason this query works if COUNT is AVG or MIN, but when I use COUNT, I get the same results for each week.  I have a table of product SKUs, category and weekly performance.  Have tried doing this a couple ways, but every way I have tried, I end up with the same results for each week.

```
SELECT 
  category_table.category, 
    COUNT(rank_table.WK_1), 
    COUNT(rank_table.WK_2), 
    COUNT(rank_table.WK_3)
FROM category_table
JOIN rank_table ON
  category_table.sku = rank_table.sku
WHERE 
    rank_table.WK_1 < 999999 
    AND rank_table.WK_2 < 999999 
    AND rank_table.WK_3 < 999999
GROUP BY category;
```

The results look something like:

```
 1. category-----|---WK_1---|---WK_2---|---WK_3---|
 2. hats---------|------100-|------100-|------100-|
 3. shirts-------|------150-|------150-|------150-|
 4. pants--------|-------50-|-------50-|-------50-|
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample?

Comment: There is no `rank` table. There is however a `rank_table` table.

Comment: @Strawberry good catch.  It is right in the query I was using.  Did not use the actual table names or column names to keep it easier to read.

Comment: I guess that's why there's an edit button

Comment: @Strawberry Ha!  Good point.  Fixed.

Comment: @Mureinik added sample data.

Comment: What if there was a wk_4?

Comment: @Strawberry There would be.  Is there an easy way to programmatically cycle through each week?  Something like a while loop where you could say while week < 10 and it would increment?  There must be.  Still learning SQL.

Comment: Yes. Instead of accepting mediocre, sticking-plaster answers, fix your broken schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your way you are just counting the number of not null values in the rows and in a inner join this number could be   the same.   if all the values  you have are not null values  you could use count( distinct  ... ) that count the number of different values

```
  SELECT 
    category_table.category, 
      COUNT(distinct rank_table.WK_1), 
      COUNT(distinct rank_table.WK_2), 
      COUNT(distinct rank_table.WK_3)
  FROM category_table
  JOIN rank_table ON
    category_table.sku = rank_table.sku
  WHERE 
      rank_table.WK_1 < 999999 
      AND rank_table.WK_2 < 999999 
      AND rank_table.WK_3 < 999999
  GROUP BY category;
```